# Converting date string to desired date format and the output is nil

Tags: swift, xcode, date, iso

I am trying to display date into tableview cell in the following format

`1996.July.10 12:08 PM` using this pattern `yyyy.MMMM.dd hh:mm aaa`

My actual date format from api is in this format `2019-12-16T05:33:43Z`

Here is the code that I used for conversion

```
if let dateString: String = articleListVM.articles[indexPath.row].publishedAt {
            print(dateString)
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MMMM.dd hh:mm aaa"
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
            print("date: \(String(describing: date))")
        }
```

Right now I am getting the following output like this

```
2019-12-16T05:33:43Z
date: nil
```

I am not sure what mistake I have done that i am getting nil, please look into this.

Comment: You need to convert first the String `2019-12-16T05:33:43Z` into a `Date` respecting its dateformat. THEN, you convert that date using your code into the desired `String`.

Comment: @Bhargav I've amended my answer to provide information on how to format the date for output using a second `DateFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a minor issue with the date format you are specifying.  Your date format should actually be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

Therefore, change your code to:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

Output:

```
date: Optional(2019-12-16 05:33:43 +0000)
```

**Edit following further information from OP in comments**

In order to convert from a string in one format to a date, and then to another date format, you need two `DateFormatter`s.  The following will convert the original string date and then output it the date to another format:

```
let dateString: String = "2019-12-16T05:33:43Z"
print(dateString)

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
{
  print("date: \(String(describing: date))")

  let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
  outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
  outputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MMMM.dd hh:mm aaa"
  let outputDate = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
  print("date: \(String(describing: outputDate))")
}
```

Output:

```
2019-12-16T05:33:43Z
date: 2019-12-16 05:33:43 +0000
date: 2019.December.16 05:33 AM
```

Comment: I just figured out. Thank you for your help and time. we solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following solution, I have tested its working fine

```
let inputdateString: String = "2019-12-16T05:33:43Z"
let dateFormatter  = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ"
let inputDate = dateFormatter.date(from: inputdateString )!
print("Input date: \(String(describing: inputDate))")
//Converting to Display Date, you can reuse same date formater 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.MMMM.dd hh:mm a"
let displayDate = dateFormatter.string(from: inputDate)
print("display date: \(String(describing: displayDate))")
```

output:-

```
Input date: 2019-01-16 05:33:43 +0000
display date: 2019.January.16 11:03 AM
```

Comment: `Z` is a timezone specifier, NOT a string literal.  This is not the correct answer

Comment: I got the same output. Could you please tell me how to get my date displayed in this "1996.July.10 12:08 PM" format in my label.